# Fetching swagger-ui returns 404 in a ASP.NET Core 3.1 app in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

When loading the /swagger/index.html page the browser can't find the swagger-ui resources required when deployed to an App Servicce in Azure, returning 404. It works when running locally. My setup is:

```
  services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
  {
      options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
      {
          Title = "Nexus WebApp",
          Version = "v1"
      });
      options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());
               
  });
```

```
 var builder = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder();

 builder.UseSwagger();

 builder.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
 {
     options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Nexus WebApp");
 });

 var pipeline = builder.Build();

 endpoints.Map("/swagger", pipeline)
     .RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute());
 endpoints.Map("/swagger/index.html", pipeline)
     .RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute());
 endpoints.Map("/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json", pipeline)
     .RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

I've tried with a relative path fro the swagger endpoint like so `..\swagger\v1/swagger.json`, I've tried specifying a RoutePrefix all to no avail unfortunately. I'm aware similar questions have been asked but unfortunately none seem to help.

Does anyone have any clues?

**Update**

These are the resources it is returning 404 for:

- https://{domain}/swagger/swagger-ui.css
- https://{domain}/swagger/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
- https://{domain}/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js

Comment: I'm afraid not, simply replacing my code with your code is not an answer.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @KristofferJälén I have the same exact problem in AKS, did you find a solution?

Comment: @JohnNyingi Yes, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71518339/909180).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, your implementation is wrong. Here is the complete `Startup` code for setting up Swagger UI in NET Core:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
namespace IDGSwaggerDemo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion
            (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);   
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "Swagger Demo",
                    Description = "Swagger Demo for ValuesController",
                    TermsOfService = "None",
                    Contact = new Contact() { Name = "Joydip Kanjilal",
                    Email = "joydipkanjilal@yahoo.com",
                    Url = "www.google.com"
                }
                });
            });
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
       IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Check out [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3400084/how-to-use-swagger-in-aspnet-core.html#:%7E:text=Install%20Swagger%20middleware%20in%20ASP.Net%20Core&text=To%20do%20this%2C%20select%20the,AspNetCore%20and%20install%20it.) tutorial for more enhanced Swagger implementation.

Comment: I think there might be some confusion, I've edited my question title to say Core 3.1, the other question you refer to talks about Framework if I'm not mistaken. Also the index page itself doesn't return 404, only the swagger-ui resources (js and css files)

Comment: Yes, Framework and core are different. Thanks for updating, let me look into this. What do you mean by "swagger-ui resources (js and css files)"?

Comment: have updated with the exact resources it can't find, hope that helps, thanks

Comment: But, are these resources breaking your Swagger UI? What is the issue?

Comment: Yes, with no js or css the page is blank

Comment: Can you try deplyoing above code once? As I told before, your `endpoint.map` code piece looks wrong .

Comment: Just checking in to see if you got a chance to look at my response above.

Comment: That endpoint.Map code is just adding an authorize attribute to those routes. These endpoints have to be secure. In what way does it look "wrong"? I can't see how it would work differently locally vs in Azure.

Comment: Your code is using endpoints = IEndpointRouteBuilder, which is not required. That is why it's giving issue. Can you pls update your code to the above code which I have shared?

Comment: How do you suggest I authorise the index page?

Comment: https://ppolyzos.com/2017/10/30/add-jwt-bearer-authorization-to-swagger-and-asp-net-core/ - this is JWT token auth. Which auth are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after struggling with this for hours, I managed to get it to work. Note that I have the special requirement that I have a Web API for which I want controllers to use Bearer token authentication, and at the same time I want the Swagger UI to be protected by OIDC.

I have left out parts in the class that are not relevant for this answer.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddMvc();

// Add authentication to web API
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);

// Add authentication to web app for Swagger authorization
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger") && context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```